# Forgot Password function, django

Tags: django, passwords, reset

I followed the code here:
http://drumcoder.co.uk/blog/2010/apr/09/django-reset-password/
as well as here:
http://shrenikp.webs.com/apps/blog/entries/show/7133721-implement-forgot-password-on-customer-ui-
and here:
http://blog.montylounge.com/2009/07/12/django-forgot-password/

This is the code I currently wish to work with and what I have it at currently

**[base.html]**

```
            <form name="login_form" action="/login/" method="post" accept-charset="utf-8" style="display: inline">
                {% csrf_token %}
                Username: <input type="text" name="username" value="" /><br />
                Password: <input type="password" name="password" value="" /><br />
                <input type="submit" value="submit" value = "" id ="submit" />
                <p><a href="{% url password_reset %}">Forgot password?</a></p>
            </form>
```

**[url.py]**

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^password_reset/$', 'django.contrib.auth.views.password_reset', name='password_reset'),
    (r'^password_reset/done/$', 'django.contrib.auth.views.password_reset_done'),
    (r'^reset/(?P[0-9A-Za-z]+)-(?P.+)/$', 'django.contrib.auth.views.password_reset_confirm'),
    (r'^reset/done/$', 'django.contrib.auth.views.password_reset_complete'),
)
```

I get an error something like this:

```
unknown specifier: ?P[
```

this line error for some reason...    (r'^reset/(?P[0-9A-Za-z]+)-(?P.+)/$'
any help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're going to need to change it to this:

```
(r'^reset/(?P<uidb36>[-\w]+)/(?P<token>[-\w]+)/$', 'django.contrib.auth.views.password_reset_confirm')
```

You need to add the tag `{% csrf_token %}` after your `<form>` mark-up in your template. Try that.

Comment: Yes thank you! that did the trick. But Now i have this error Forbidden (403)
CSRF verification failed. Request aborted.  Would you be able to help me?

Comment: wierd, I looked up what url rule the django lib is using and its: `(r'^account/reset/(?P<uidb36>[0-9A-Za-z]{1,13})-(?P<token>[0-9A-Za-z]{1,13}-[0-9A-Za-z]{1,20})/$'`